# ActionScript * datatype - what is it?

Tags: actionscript-3

In Flex I can specify a `*` as datatype.
What is it and how should I use it.

I've written a `inArray()` method that takes as argument something to search for and something to search in. The "something to search for" looks like a great candidate for the `*` datatype.

Should I not use it?

Thank you.

Comment: This question has nothing to do with flex, but is about AS3.

Comment: "nothing to do" is wrong and I was not sure if it was Flex-specific or it got inherited from AS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`*` indicates an untyped identifier.  You'd use it when you can't guarantee that the type of an object will conform to any specific class or interface definition.

Whether `*` is appropriate in your example depends on what operations you use in your search.  If you just rely on common equality operations, you should be fine, and in fact it would probably be the best choice.

Comment: Yeah, it's just `needle==haystack[i]` basically.

Answer (score 2):

The * is to AS3 as Object is to Java. See the following:

http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=03_Language_and_Syntax_11.html

Comment: That's not true. Object is to to as3 what Object is to Java.

Comment: Thanks for the link, Tony. That's what I couldn't find.

Answer (score 2):

The `*` actually explicitly says, that something has no type. In fact it's the default type, all untyped variables or functions fall back to.

It basically tells the compiler: "I don't want you to perform any typecheck on this, because this simply gets handled at runtime".

In fact `*` is *no type*. There is simply no value corresponding to it.
Please note, that only expressions of type `*` can return the value of `undefined`. Anything, that is of type `Object` (i.e. anything that is of a different type, than *no type*), can only hold `null`.

You will see that many `Array` methods use that type. That's specifically, because `Array` elements are of *no type* and can thus be `undefined`.
Therefore, I suppose you could have a slight performance difference based on whether your parameter is typed `*` or `Object` (or whether you use strict comparison or not, for that matter).

Personally, I would advise you use `*` in this case, mostly, because it is consistent with `Array` methods.

Answer (score 1):

you have to use * when strict mode of compilation is enabled. It's just 'no type', and it will be checked at runtime.